# Use of undeclared type 'UIViewControllerContextTransit'

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift. I am making custom Transition in Swift 3.

```
func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransit.ioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 0.75
}
```

i am getting error:

> Use of undeclared type 'UIViewControllerContextTransit'

Do anyone know Solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misprint in code. You need change `UIViewControllerContextTransit.ioning` to `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`
Your code will look like

```
func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 0.75
}
```